# Add effects to audio and save the new audio using FMOD in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, fmod

I am adding effects in audio file using FMOD and saving the audio with effects to the documents directory. The problem i am facing is, if the audio has stopped, FMOD keeps on writing data to the file. What should i use to stop FMOD writing data if the audio has finished ?
Below is my code...

```
- (void)startFMODToAddEffects
{
FMOD_RESULT result = FMOD_OK;

unsigned int  version       = 0;

/*
 Create a System object and initialize
 */
result = FMOD::System_Create(&system);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->getVersion(&version);
ERRCHECK(result);

if (version < FMOD_VERSION)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "You are using an old version of FMOD %08x.  This program requires %08x\n", version, FMOD_VERSION);
    exit(-1);
}

char buffer[200] = {0};
NSString *tFileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Part2.m4a", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
[tFileName getCString:buffer maxLength:200 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

char cDest[200] = {0};
NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Part2WithEffect.wav", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
[fileName getCString:cDest maxLength:200 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

result = system->setOutput(FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL | FMOD_INIT_ENABLE_PROFILE, cDest);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->createStream(buffer, FMOD_SOFTWARE, NULL, &sound);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, sound, false, &channel);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->createDSPByType(FMOD_DSP_TYPE_LOWPASS, &dsplowpass);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->addDSP(dsplowpass, NULL);
ERRCHECK(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call in the method you stop playing

> //System::release
>   system ->  release();

It should stop writing data in your file.